# How to select Max of Column value and increment accordingly in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table called `Employee` where Id's (`ID` is auto-incremented) are as follows:

```
id  
----
10  
11  
12  
13   
1000   
1001   
1002
```

My requirement is: whenever any data will be inserted from different source into `Employee` table, I want to increment only 2 digits valued ID.

Like here, if a data is inserted, then it should check for MAX(2-digit ID) and increment it as 14 and insert the data. It should not increment as 1003.

Please let me know if I am not clear.

Comment: I am looking for a sql query like this: Select MAX(ID) from Employee where ID < 1000. just to make you all understand. then increment that ID

Comment: First thought: why not fix those 3 records ( assuming there are only 3 records >1000 ) and make their IDs 14,15,16 respectively, then reseed the table to start the IDs at 17? Basically, fix your data instead of implementing some crazy solution that will only work for the next 987 records.

Comment: This is bad practice, and will eventually bite you in the ass.  I've seen this many times - I don't know why, but it seems like gaps like this bother a lot of computer nerds.  Just let it go.  I promise you will never do a better job than SQL Server at managing that ID field.  I also promise you you'll never run out of integers - I just took a tour of the integer factory, and they promised me they'll keep making more.

Comment: @sage Its juszz an example i have mentioned.. in real scenario.. there are hundreds of records

Comment: Yeah, this is a bad idea, I assume this id is used in other tables as a foreign key. You are running the risk of throwing all the other tables out of sync if you accidentally use an id that was used before.

Comment: What happens when you exceed the 9,999 values you can increment to??? This is just an awful awful idea. What about concurrency? Any time anyone tries to roll their own clever version of an identity it never works. Just don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why one may need this but you can use `DBCC CHECKIDENT` to reseed the incrementing value:

```
create table test(id int identity(1, 1), col int)

insert into test values(1),(2)

set identity_insert test on

insert into test(id, col) values(1001, 1001),(1002, 1002)

set identity_insert test off

select * from test

dbcc checkident(test, RESEED, 2)

insert into test values(3)--inserts 3, 3

select * from test
```